# WP_Query | 'post_type' doesn't work

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, custom-post-type-archives, post-type

I'm new to WP theme development and I've an issue.

I've created a custom post type 'portfolio' via CPT UI plug-in.
Now I want to create a custom query to show all the posts with the post_type = 'portfolio'.
Here is my code

```
<div class="row">

    <?php
        $args = array (
            'post-type' => 'portfolio'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


    <div class="col-sm-3 portfolio-piece">

        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>
```

Somehow it shows me the only one post 'Hello World!' with the post_type = 'post'. By the way, I don't even have this post.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 'post-type' in code instead of 'post_type'